# readthedocs build failing using aiohttp

Tags: read-the-docs

First time using readthedocs.

Firstly, is there a way to specify build with python 3.6?

My lastest build is here:
https://readthedocs.org/projects/cfanalytics/builds/6772697/
which uses python 2.7 for the build, but my project requires python >= 3.6.

Secondly,
It's failing because of an 'invalid syntax' at L125 https://github.com/raybellwaves/cfanalytics/blob/94aa21c628678f0cacf0006a92bb3740d51cca14/cfanalytics/core/cfopendata.py#L125. However, the function is an Asynchronous function hence the `async def ...` I think `aiohttp` first appeared in python 3.5 so it may be an issue with the python version?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Python interpreter to Cpython 3.X in your readthedocs Advanced Settings.

Use the link below:
https://readthedocs.org/dashboard/cfanalytics/edit/

You may need to add `autodoc_mock_imports = ['aiohttp']` in the conf.py if you use sphinx.ext.autodoc.